# iOS: right swipe gesture not responding in UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipageviewcontroller, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I am currently facing a scenario that I am using a `UIPageViewController` on a view & I want the right swipe gesture to work when user swipe right side from index value `0`, so I am trying to add a right swipe gesture to `UIPageViewController` by the following code:

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *rightRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(rightSwipeHandle:)];
rightRecognizer.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
[rightRecognizer setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];
//Edit 1
[self.pageViewController.view addGestureRecognizer:rightRecognizer];
```

but, while I am adding gesture to `pageviewcontroller` I am getting following error message (Solved by @Lyndsey Scott answer)

```
no visible interface uipageviewcontroller declares the selector addgesturerecognizer
```

Can anyone guide me that how can I implement the right swipe in this `pageViewController`

**Edit 1:** Replaced the code provided by @Lyndsey Scott, removed the error, but problem still exists that I am not able to trigger that swipe event.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to the gesture to the `UIPageViewController`'s view:

```
[self.pageViewController.view addGestureRecognizer:rightRecognizer];
```

**Edit in response to your edit:**

The swipe gesture won't work if you haven't implemented any `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` methods to allow for the `UIPageViewController`'s swipe gesture and your swipe gesture to be recognized simultaneously. Right now, your swipe is essentially being blocked by the page controller's gesture. You could change that by implementing the `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`, setting `rightRecognizer.delegate = self;`, and overriding `gestureRecognizer: shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:otherGestureRecognizer` such that it returns true in the case that both gesture recognizers are triggered.

But if you want the page to flip and your gesture to be recognized at the time of that page flip, adding the extra swipe gesture is unnecessary since you can simply trigger your method upon page turn; for example in `pageViewController:didFinishAnimating:previousViewControllers: transitionCompleted:`.

Comment: This has removed my error but the selector is not getting called on right swipe. Any suggestions?

Comment: @RajatDeepSingh The problem is that it's being blocked by the default recognizer... You could have the gestures be recognized simultaneously, but if you want the page to swipe *and* the gesture to be recognized at the same time, adding the swipe gesture is unnecessary since you can simply trigger your method upon page turn...

Comment: @RajatDeepSingh - Think your question has been answered. You are asking another question. please accept the answer and post the new question.

Comment: @LyndseyScott Can you please guide how to recognize multiple gestures, that whether it is of `UIPageViewController` or `UISwipeGestureRecognizer`

Comment: @LyndseyScott I tried your answer of overriding `gestureRecognizer: shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:otherGestureRecognizer `, but it is not getting called. Even I tried to solve this issue using `pageViewController:didFinishAnimating:previousViewControllers: transitionCompleted:` before posting the question but this is also not getting called when I swipe left to right from index `0`

Comment: @RajatDeepSingh You need to implement the delegates for `gestureRecognizer: shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:otherGestureRecognizer` to be called.

Comment: @LyndseyScott I have added `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` in my code.

Comment: @RajatDeepSingh You also have to set `rightRecognizer.delegate = self`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81078/discussion-between-rajat-deep-singh-and-lyndsey-scott).

Comment: @LyndseyScott You are right, this worked after adding delegate, just one last thing can you please tell that how can I detect that when I have to perform that action like how can I detect that currently page view controller is 0 & right swiped is called.

Comment: @RajatDeepSingh That's a complicated question that depends on the specifics of your code. I'd recommend posting that question as a separate question in the forum.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to add the gesture recognizer, if you implement the protocol correctly it should work out of the box.

The point of `UIPageViewController` is to not have to do it manually.

Comment: I guess you misunderstood it, I wanted to do additional action on extreme left paging view, I want to do a action when user swipes from left to right when the paging index is `0`